# DataAnnotations in monodroid

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin, xamarin-studio, xamarin.android

I have some models in a core library I'd like to share with a MonoDroid project, but `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` is not available to the monodroid target.  I tried grabbing the code for `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` from the mono source and compiling the source code into the project but ended up going into a rabbit hole trying to get it to compile with all it's dependencies.

Anyone have any suggestions or steps on how I can include that namespace in Xamarin monodroid and monotouch projects?

If not, maybe a suggestion on how I can include my model class library in my xamarin projects without build errors.

Answer (score 0):

Soner, it would appear they are still not available at the moment in Xamarin. However, I did not have any issue using DataContract , and DataMember annotations in my Portable Class Libraries. If your not using PCL's I highly recommend it for any code sharing scenarios anyways. Good luck!